# Entity Framework Execute Function not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Attempting to call an SQL Function via Entity Framework and no matter the method I try I always the same error being

```
The FunctionImport 'fn_SearchEmployer' could not be found in the container 'MyDatabase'.
```

My code is

```
public virtual ObjectResult<EmployerModel> EmployerSearch(string employerName, int userId)
    {
        var employerNameParam = new ObjectParameter("employerName", employerName);
        var userIdParam = new ObjectParameter("userId", userId);
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<EmployerModel>("fn_SearchEmployer", employerNameParam, userIdParam);
    }
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried Try [schema].[fn_SearchEmployer]?

Comment: @Democrats I tried adding my schema and it hasn't changed anything, it's still unable to locate the FunctionImport